# Possible to Store API Data?

Tags: wordpress, api, request

I want to use an API to display product information on my Wordpress site but the company says it will charge me after 1000 server requests per month.

Is it possible to store the requested data so I can reuse it and not pass the quota?
Would there be any potential problems?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the reason they implement a limit like that is to encourage people to cache (store) the data on their site. If everyone was to code their site to request the data via API every time a page was displayed it would quickly overwhelm the API servers.

There are many ways to cache the data, 
The simplest would be to move all your API calls into a cron job that runs every night and places the results of each API request in a different file on the disk - Then you can change your webpage code to read this file instead of connecting to the API url.   (You could also use filemtime() to check the age of the file and automatically request it if it's more then a day old, but you risk going over your limit if your server is busy and multiple requests come in as the file expires triggering multiple api requests - so the cron job is the safe route)

The down side to caching the entire response is you have to parse it every time you display  a page - But if you want the simplest solution for a simple API call - that would be it.

The correct way would be to parse the response in your cron job and store the data in your Database in a way that's easy to work with. Then you can request just the data you need from the database - which will make your entire site run faster and use less memory.

Comment: Your response was so helpful. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are developing a Wordpress site, I would highly suggest researching and implementing the [Transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API).

It works very close to a cron job and will provide you with a simpler caching solution that  you can manage through a Wordpress Plugin or Theme. It works just like the Wordpress Options API but with added expiration times for the settings.